# Error en setvalue en FormControlName

Tags: angular

Siguiendo este tutorial: https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName#use-with-ngmodel

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
form = new FormGroup({
  first: new FormControl('Nancy', Validators.minLength(2)),
  last: new FormControl('Drew'),
});
```

y voy a asignar valores a mi form

```
this.personaService.get(id).then(persona=> this.form.setValue(persona));
```

persona tiene lo siguiente:

```
{first: 'Carson', last: 'Drew', adress: 'Calle stackoverflow'}
```

y el error que me da es:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find form control with name: adress.
```

¿cómo puedo evitar inicializar adress en el this.form? El API me devuelve otros atributos pero solo usaré el 'first' and 'last', NOTA: no se puede cambiar el api para que solo me devuelva lo que necesito

Answer (score 0):

Por un lado puedes usar la destructuración para extraer solo las propiedades del objeto persona que necesites.

Que en tu caso quedaría algo así:

```
this.personaService.get(id).then(({first, last}) => this.form.setValue({first, last}));
```

---

O si quieres seguir usando el objeto de la api, y simplemente quieres deshacerte del mensaje de error, puedes usar el metodo `patchValue` en vez de `setValue`

```
this.personaService.get(id).then(persona=> this.form.patchValue(persona));
```

un saludo

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, pero si en vez de 2 tuviera unos 20 parametros seria muy tediosa labor, como lo tngo funciona solo queria evitr ese error en la consola de javascript

Comment: Sí, en el caso de que sean muchos parámetros aparte de tedioso sería poco legible. En ese caso lo mejor que puedes hacer es extraer la lógica de transformación de un objeto a otro a una función. // Si solo quieres deshacerte del error, puedes usar `patchValue` en vez de `setValue`

Comment: gracias, eso me sirve